# Angular $http Unable to send Content type header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an absurd error while using angular $http with post method.

While sending $http POST requests, it's not attaching Content-type header and due to which i get an error "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404". 
This is my code-

```
    var obj={
        "mobile":"hello",
        "password":"asjd"
    }
$http({
    url: 'http://cbsatwork.com/laundry/api-authentication',
    method: 'POST',
    data:obj,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    })
```

Although if i remove the "data:obj" line from the code, it works and i get usual response from the server.
I have looked into many answers, but could not get anything working for me.

**EDIT:**
I tried using $.ajax() method from jQuery, and it worked totally fine. no issues. so i do not think that there is any issue with my server.

Comment: Do you make this request to WCF or WebApi  backend? If so  I can suggest you adding CORS enabled attribute and your problem is probably related to CORS . https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: What if you pass the method before the the url ?

Comment: what is the domain you're sending the request from?

Comment: @Korte tried it.. not working..

Comment: @Maximus from my localhost. but that should not be an issue, since i am getting proper response if i remove data attribute from this code.

Comment: @DagaArihant, do you have proxy setup, configured CORS on the server or running a browser with disabled security check? Otherwise because of CORS it wouldn't work since domain in `url` is different from `localhost` and this error `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP` indicates the problem with host

Comment: @DagaArihant, preflight requests are sent as OPTIONS and don't have body. check if your server can handle OPTIONS request. again, the first request is OPTIONS, not POST

Answer (score 1):

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

This error indicates that most likely there's a CORS problem. A browser sends two requests. The first request is `OPTIONS` and the other is `POST`, which you configure in your example. The problem is unlikely to be with the `Content-Type` header, because this header is sent using `POST`, not `OPTIONS`. And it's the `OPTIONS` request that fails. Check if your server supports `OPTIONS` request and sends back correct CORS required headers

Comment: Thank you Maximum, But i get this in my response headers - 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE,HEAD. And i even put a cors extension in my browser, but it's still not working.

Comment: Plus, The same happens when i use $.jax from jquery instead of $http.
function submit(){
   var obj={'mobile':'asd','password':'asdk'};
   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"http://www.cbsatwork.com/laundry/api-authentication",
    data:obj
   });
  }
This works perfectly fine.

The only difference betwwen two requests(1 sent by $http and another by $.ajax is of a header- Content-Type)

Comment: ok, can you use fiddler to catch two requests (OPTONS and POST) and their responses?

Comment: I could not, what you are saying might be true, i mean, yes i am able to call the api when i am using the same server, and i cannot call the api when i am not on the same server, (Which means it might be a cors issue). But then why am i able to do the same using jQuery's $.ajax but not $http.

Comment: @DagaArihant, please post the full code with $.ajax

Comment: function submit(){
   var obj={'mobile':'asd','password':'asdk'};
   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"http://www.cbsatwork.com/laundry/api-authentication",
    data:obj
   });
  }

Comment: can you post request/response for both $http and $ajax scenarios? you can capture them with fiddler. each should have OPTIONS and POST requests